# Cloud Run: endpoint that runs a function as background job

Tags: python, asynchronous, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-tasks

I am trying to deploy a rest api in cloud run where one endpoint launches an async job. The job is defined inside a function in the code.

It seems one way to do it is to use Cloud Task, but this would mean to make a self-call to another endpoint of the deployed api. Specifically, to create an auxiliary endpoint that contains the job code (e.g. `/run-my-function`) and another one to set the queue to cloud task that launches the `/run-my-function`?

Is this the right way to do it or I have misunderstand something? In case it's the right way how to specify the url of the `/run-my-function` endpoint without explicitly hard-code the cloud run deployed uRL name?

The code for the endpoint that launches the endpoint with the `run-my-function` code would be:

```
from google.cloud import tasks_v2
client = tasks_v2.CloudTasksClient()
project = 'myproject'
queue = 'myqueue'
location = 'mylocation'
url = 'https://cloudrunservice-abcdefg-ca.b.run.app/run-my-function'
service_account_email = '12345@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com'

parent = client.queue_path(project, location, queue)
task = {
            "http_request": {  
                "http_method": tasks_v2.HttpMethod.POST,
                'url': url,
                "oidc_token": {"service_account_email": service_account_email},
            }
        }
response = client.create_task(parent=parent, task=task)
```

However, this requires to hard-code the service name `https://cloudrunservice-abcdefg-ca.b.run.app` and to define an auxiliary endpoint `/run-my-function` that can be called via http

Comment: You could use environment variables, Secret Manager or Cloud Storage to store the URL. https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/environment-variables

Comment: You are correct, it's the right way and you need to use the full qualified URL in your Cloud Task. What's your concern? the fact to get the Cloud Run root URL?

Comment: @John Hanley storing the url would be as hard-coding it. I think it's not a sensitive information as in any case the url will be public for the api.

Comment: @guillaume blaquiere, my concern is that in case I make a fresh deployment in cloud run the url may change. So I'm trying to get a more robust way to do it

Comment: Your question states **However, this requires to hard-code the service name**, so what is the question? You must store the URL someplace. I thought you were asking where should you store the URL.

Comment: If you **make a fresh deployment** the URL is partially generated from random alpha-numeric letters and you will need to save the generated URL. If you update an existing deployment the URL does not change. Note: I think you can read the metadata to get the instance name and then build the URL from that - I have not verified that however. The service account assigned to Cloud Run will need IAM permission to read metadata.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am trying to understand whether it's possible to choose the url name for the cloud run deployment or to make the call to cloud task using a relative url (as it's inside the same api). This way I could avoid saving the url and be sure that everything works in case of a fresh deployment.

Comment: The service URL is generated by Google. I am not aware of any options to influence the URL that is generated.

Comment: A common feature not provided by Cloud Run Managed is service discovery. Perhaps Ahmet's **runsd** project will give you some ideas. https://github.com/ahmetb/runsd Also, the article that @guillaume wrote is very good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you are able to get the Cloud Run URL without hardcoding it or setting it in an environment variable.

You can have a look to a [previous article that I wrote](https://medium.com/google-cloud/3-solutions-to-mitigate-the-cold-starts-on-cloud-run-8c60f0ae7894), in the gracefull termison part. I provide a working code in Go, not so difficult to re-implement in Python.

Here the principle:

- Get the Region and the project Number from the [Metadata server](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/metadata/default-metadata-values). Keep in mind that [Cloud Run has specific metadata](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/container-contract#metadata-server) like the region
- Get the K_SERVICE env var (it's a standard Cloud Run env var)
- Perform a call to the [Cloud Run Rest API to get the service detail](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest/v1/namespaces.services/get) and customize the request with the data got previously
- Extract the `status.url` JSON entry from the response.

Now you have it!

*Let me know if you have difficulties to achieve that. I'm not good at Python, but I will be able to write that piece of code!*

Comment: Thank you! It sounds quite an interesting solution